# Pie Chart Objective-C QuartzCore

Tags: ios, objective-c, pie-chart, quartz-core

I'm having trouble making a pie chart in Objective-C with QuartzCore. I don't want to use a library. It keep crashing at the line "for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_sliceArray count]; i++)" in my drawPieChart method and giving me an error: "exc_bad_access(code=exc_i386_gpflt)". Here is my full for the PieChart.m file. Any suggestions on what's going? Thanks in advance.

```
#import "PieChart.h"

@implementation PieChart

@synthesize circleRadius = _circleRadius;
@synthesize sliceArray = _sliceArray;
@synthesize colorsArray = _colorsArray;


-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    //Set up colorSlices
    NSArray *colorSlices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3], nil];

    self.sliceArray = colorSlices;

    //set up the colors for the colorSlices
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor,
                       (id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,
                       (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                       (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor, nil];

    self.colorsArray = colors;

}

return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

//get the current graphics context so Quartz can draw into it, and pass that context to our drawPieChart method.
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self drawPieChart:context];

 }

 - (void)drawPieChart:(CGContextRef)context  {
CGPoint circleCenter = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2);

// Set the radius of your pie chart
self.circleRadius = 100;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_sliceArray count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%lu", i);
    // Determine start angle
    CGFloat startValue = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        startValue += [[_sliceArray objectAtIndex:k] floatValue];
    }
    CGFloat startAngle = startValue * 2 * M_PI - M_PI/2;

    // Determine end angle
    CGFloat endValue = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j >= 0; j--) {
        endValue += [[_sliceArray objectAtIndex:j] integerValue];
    }

    CGFloat endAngle = endValue * 2 * M_PI - M_PI/2;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (CGColorRef)[_colorsArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, circleCenter.x, circleCenter.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, circleCenter.x, circleCenter.y, self.circleRadius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why that for loop should be crashing. It's really hard to debug code by looking at it in a forum post. I suggest you step through it in the debugger and check your variable values to see what's going on.

Comment: I just copy and pasted this into an empty project. Works fine. Try cleaning your build folder and relaunching Xcode. I am bothered by your synthesis of properties though, why do you have to do this? Properties have been auto-synthesised for ages now... Only makes sense if you've overridden the getters and setters, have you done this? Make sure they're getting set correctly if you are.

Comment: I also can't help but get bothered by the line `for (int j = 0; j >= 0; j--)`. You do realise this will only ever be called once?

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for the response. I did some print statements and tried debugging by stepping through and it seems that sometimes _slicesArray is populated and sometimes not.

Comment: Are you using ARC? (If not, you should be.) Is there any code you haven't shown that might be setting _slices to nil?

Comment: originaluser2 Thanks for the response. I cleaned the build folder but still the same thing. Did it actually end up building the pie chart for you? Also I'm still new to programming and Objective-C so I was following a tutorial and they had used the @synthesize for the properties. The tutorial was older. I'm still trying to figure out my way through all of this. Thanks for pointing out my for-loop error. I changed it so now int j = i (from my "for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_sliceArray count]; i++)" loop).

Comment: @dcotter sure it's working, have a look: https://infinit.io/_/hQ5ifKb (although now I think about it the orange isn't drawing). Try having a look outside of your `PieChart` class (if you're sure that you're posting all your code, although it would also nice to also see the .h) and see if you are ever interacting with the slices property on the view from another class. Yes, you should delete the `@synthesize` lines, they're redundant.

Comment: @DuncanC yes I'm using ARC. No I'm showing all of the code and I'm not resetting it to nil anywhere. It's weird because sometimes I'll also get a crash that says "-[__NSSetM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbcf3633c10" and not on that line. It is just a majority of the time it crashes on "for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_sliceArray count]; i++)"

Comment: I created a git repo for it if you're willing to take a quick look? git@github.com:dcotter1208/PieChart.git

Comment: @dcotter the problem is your properties have the keyword `assign`, which is usually used for primitives, so it's messing with the arrays. remove the `assign` keyword. I can only assume you're following a very outdated tutorial.

Comment: That was it! and yes it was a very old tutorial. Most of the recent tutorials showed the use of libraries but for my particular situation I needed to build one from scratch. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Also yes the orange isn't showing up which is weird but at least everything else is drawing. Thanks!

Comment: To get orange to draw I needed to change integerValue to floatValue in the following code: for (int j = 0; j >= 0; j--) {
        endValue += [[_sliceArray objectAtIndex:j] integerValue];
    }